# Заполнение структуры запихнуть в функцию

Tags: c++, visual-c++, функции, структуры

Имеется структура

```
struct Informer
    {
        char item[20];
        char Platform[20];
        char TimeBack[20];
};
```

И заполнение его, из файла

```
ifstream in;
Informer mas[20];
in.open("1.txt");
int i = 1;
int n = 0;
while (!in.eof())
{
    n++;
    if (n != 4)
        switch (n)
    {
        case 1: in >> mas[i].item;
            break;
        case 2: in >> mas[i].Platform;
            break;
        case 3: in >> mas[i].TimeBack;
    }
    else { n = 0; i++; }
}
```

Как запихнуть это в функцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто запихнуть это в функцию. Передавать в качестве параметра указатель на структуру (т.е. на первый элемент массива структур - сделать mas параметром этой функции), а функция будет заполнять массив данными из файла. Также желательно передавать через параметр максимальное количество считываемых элементов (размер этого массива, чтобы не выйти за его пределы). Третьим параметром может быть имя файла (открываем внутри функции) или уже открытый поток (открываем заранее до вызова функции). И возвращать можно признак успеха/ошибки или количество реально считанных элементов (тогда 0 автоматически будет соответствовать ошибкам открытия/чтения и т.п.).